# I want to reset interface count

Tags: linux, centos

In centOS 5 is there anyway to reset /proc/net/dev  count ?
instead of reboot the server or reload NIC drivers ? 
I am using e1000e drivers for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any options to reset that counter under EL5 without a reboot or unloading and reloading the e1000e module after an `ifdown`.